Смена раскладки клавиатуры на отжатии клавиш
Пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы раскладка переключалась с помощью ctrl+shift, но только тогда, когда я отпускаю клавиши. Это необходимо, поскольку если вы хотите ввести другое сочетание клавиш, которое начинается с ctrl+shift (например, ctrl+shift+t чтобы открыть новую вкладку в терминале), то вместо ctrl+shift+t введётся только ctrl+shift, переключиться раскладка (чего я не хотел!) и затем введётся просто буква t.
Пожалуйста подскажите, как мне настроить переключение раскладки на отпускании клавиш? Я использую wayland, kde
